# "He thanked me for the present {I sent / I had sent} him"

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

Which of these sentences is correct?

> 1.​ My friend thanked me for the present **I sent** him.
>
> 2.​ My friend thanked me for the present **I had sent** him.

If both are correct, which of them is more precise?

Answer (score 3):

Both sentences are technically correct.

Which one you use largely comes down to how long ago you sent him the gift - if it was relatively recently, I'd use #1, if it was a while ago, #2.

Answer (score 1):

Both tenses used in this attributive clause are correct.

Your first sentence is more used in daily life, and it simply means your friend thanked you for receiving that present from you.

The second sentence lays more stress on that you had sent your friend a present before, so he or she thanked you for your previous favor.  The past perfect tense reflects the time sequence of two different actions in the past.